# socketIO_client (python) makes cpu spin and crashes

Tags: python, websocket, raspberry-pi, socket.io

I am trying to use socketIO_client in python and I am pretty successful with it, however when I let the program below run for a while (like an hour), it crashes and if I look at the system information with the 'top' command I can see **the CPU is spinning** at something like 80 or 90%.

PS: this happens only on my raspberry, so it might be due to an implementation of the python socketio module on ARM?

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there any socket I should close? I am not very familiar with sockets...

Here below my code:

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, BaseNamespace

class MainNamespace(BaseNamespace):

        def on_message(self, message):
            try:
                    typestr = message["depth"]["type_str"]
                    price_int  = int(message["depth"]["price_int"])
                    total_volume_int = long(message["depth"]["total_volume_int"])
                    print "price_int:%s total_volume_int:%s"  % (price_int,total_volume_int)
            except:
                    pass

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
            mainSocket = SocketIO('socketio.mtgox.com', 80)
            chatSocket = mainSocket.connect('/mtgox',MainNamespace)
            mainSocket.wait()
    except Exception, e:
            print e
```

Comment: Kill the try/except, my guess is that it's masking the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote socketIO-client in v0.5 so that it uses coroutines instead of threads to save memory.  The external API remains the same.

```
pip install -U socketIO-client
```

Does v0.5 fix your issue?